# How to add a custom WCF-Protocol-Channel to existing Binding

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, behavior, channel

Im trying to write my own WCF-Protocol-Channel with no specific functionality.
To this channel, I want to add some behaviors to lookup the SOAP-Message before processed by the webservice and after processing through the webservice.
But I cannot find any hint how to add a custom channel to a default-binding like basicHttpBinding or something else.
Background is, that I want to specify the order of processing the behaviors in the channelstack. Or to react to a SOAP-Message as soon as possible, if a damage was detected.

Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only configure the channels order in a custom binding. regardless if you are in a situation that you need to control behaviors order this may hint on some complexity. consider if message inspectors are not enough for you.

Comment: Is there any Documentation of the used Channels in the predefined bindings? I could implement a custom binding and than add the transport-channel and the protocol-channels of the basicHttpBinding plus my custom Channel incl behaviors. Do you know, If this is possible
Thanks a lot

Comment: it is not possible to add channels to non custom bindings directly. of course if you create the binding from code with new BasicHttpBinding() you could always turn it to a custom binding by calling b.CreateBindingElements() and then push your element